# Comparing 2 text columns in a data range

Tags: string, excel, text, formula

I have 2 excel sheets with addresses which I would like to compare. One sheet has more addresses then the other and both sheet have column B for addresses. I want the sheet with more address to identify which addresses do exist in the other sheet and return TRUE if they exist. If the address does not exist then it should return the Address in the result column so I know which rows of data to remove and which one to keep. Please note that the addresses are not in any order and beacause of other data in the sheet I can not order them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Thank you for the Answer ... I have managed to get the formula correct but I have extra spaces at the end of the text line in each column and I want them to be truncated in this formula. please could someone help.

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,$BL$3:$BL$781,0)),B3,"True")

Only the spaces at the end of the string needs truncating.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** of the first sheet enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,Sheet2!B:B,0)),B1,"True")
```

and copy down.

For example:

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you so much that was a great help and save me a lot of Aggravation.